# Не запускается PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

У меня стоит 6 версия PHPStorm из архива. При попытке запуска выдаёт сообщение (JDK установлен):

> No JVM could be found on your system. Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME to point to an installed 32-bit JDK or JRE or download a JRE from www.java.com

Что делать дальше, может кто подскажет?

Comment: Посмотрите https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у тебя в системе не прописан путь переменным среды для JDK.

Проверь какой у тебя путь к папке **jre/bin** . Что-то типо вот этого ***C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin***

Скопируй СВОЙ путь.
Затем щелкни правой кнопкой мыши на Мой компьютер-> Свойства-> Дополнительные параметры системы-> Окружающая среда переменных-> Путь (в низу)-> "Изменить-"> Помести точку с запятой (;) в конец текста и вставь путь файла, который ты скопировал ранее СРАЗУ после точку с запятой.

Удачи!

Comment: Не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

В системных переменных нужно создать новую переменную с именем «JAVA_HOME» и прописать в значении путь к папке с версией jre (без "\bin") например «C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181»